# Combination or Permutations - identification

Tags: permutations, combinations

Car $A$ can take $5$ passengers, car $B$ can take $6$ passengers, car C can take $2$ passengers. Find the number of ways that $11$ passengers and a couple to travel in the $3$ cars.

$${13 \choose{5}} + {13\choose {6}} + {13\choose 2} = 3081$$

Is this step correct？

Comment: Are there any conditions (e.g. couple must be in the same car, preference for seats, etc) ? Is this the **exact** question reproduced ? If you have tried to give the **gist** of it, pl. reproduce exact question.

Comment: No any conditions , just arrange them in three cars

Comment: The couple, I assume, have to travel together. So, that leaves splitting the question up in three ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With no special conditions, (as you say), there are 2 fundamental errors in your answer.

(i) Once you seat 5 in a car, there are only 8 left to seat in the other cars, and so on.

(ii) You do not add, you use the multiplicative principle

Try ${13\choose 5} \cdot {8\choose 6}\cdot {2\choose 2}$

*Note:*

(a) The last term can be left out as whoever remains automatically goes into the 3rd car

(b) Try and see what happens if you seat people in the 6-seater first.

Answer (score 0):

Your question implies that 2 people always have to travel together.
Your probabilities have to be multiplied, the last remaining car always has one way to get the last passengers.

Couple in car 1:

$\left(P\vert c1\right) = 
\begin{pmatrix}11\\
3
\end{pmatrix} \cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}8\\
6
\end{pmatrix}
\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}2\\
2
\end{pmatrix}
$

Couple in car 2:

$\left(P\vert c1\right) = 
\begin{pmatrix}11\\
5
\end{pmatrix} \cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}6\\
4
\end{pmatrix}\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}2\\
2
\end{pmatrix}
$

Couple in car 3:

$\left(P\vert c1\right) = 
\begin{pmatrix}11\\
6
\end{pmatrix}\cdot 
\begin{pmatrix}5\\
5
\end{pmatrix}
$

Where
$\begin{pmatrix}2\\
2
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}5\\
5
\end{pmatrix}
=1
$